# Is There a Problem with This Professor's Proof Concerning Interior and Boundary Points?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Here is a professor's solution to the exercise which states, " Prove that if $x$ is an isolated point of a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ is a boundary point of $S$."

[image]

The professor derived a contradiction upon assuming that for an arbitrary neighborhood $N$ centered at an isolated point $x$ of $S$, we have $N \subseteq S$, so he then proceeds in saying that every $N$ must have a noenmpty intersection with $S^c$. But I feel that there is something wrong with his argument: Using mathematical logic, we can represent his assumption that every $N$ is a subset of $S$ as $\forall \, N : p(N)$ where $p(N)$ means, "$N$ is contained in $S$." He then showed that this assumption is false, so $\sim \forall \, N : p(N) \equiv \exists \, N : \, \sim p(N)$ is true, which means there are some $N$'s that are not contained in $S$. But this information is not sufficient in concluding as to whether or not there is at least one $N$ contained in $S$; it just means not every $N$ is contained in $S$. But if I am right, how can he proceed with his proof since whatever result he deduces about $N$ after the contradiction does not necessarily apply to all $N$?

I hope what I am trying to convey is clear, and I thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifiers you have do not reflect the proof. Here, the professor wants to prove $$\forall N, \lnot(N\subseteq S)$$ and proceeds by contradiction. After taking an arbitrary $N$, (s)he shows that $N\subseteq S$ would lead to a contradiction. I.e., what is showed is $$\forall N, ((N\subseteq S)\Rightarrow \bot)$$ which is logically equivalent to 
$$\forall N, (\bot \lor \lnot(N\subseteq S))$$
i.e.
$$\forall N, \lnot(N\subseteq S).$$

Comment: Thank you for your insight! So would the author's proof be considered a proof by contradiction? If so, why is the quantifier $\forall$ instead of $\exists$, assuming to the contrary that $x \not \in \mathrm{bd} \, S$?

Comment: I would say that, phrased as it currently is, part of it (i.e., a "lemma" of the proof) is shown by contradiction. It's not the whole proof, however -- only part of it.

Comment: Okay. One more question--Can we slightly change the professor's argument as follows. Let $N$ be an arbitrary subset of $S$. Because $x$ is an isolated point, there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*$ that misses $S$, which implies that $N^* \cap S^c \neq \varnothing$. But then $N \cap N^* \neq \varnothing$, because either $N \subseteq N^*$ or $N^* \subseteq N$, depending on the lengths of $N$ and $N^*$, respectively. But this contradicts the assumption that every $N \subseteq S$, so $s$ must be a boundary point given that $x \in S$.

Comment: I'm a bit tired, but I don't think your argument goes through as such. The facts that there exists $y\in N^\ast\cap S^c$ and that $N\cap N^\ast \neq \emptyset$ do not imply that $x\in N$, for instance (which you seem to use to say that $N\subseteq S$ is contradicted).

Answer (score 0):

Note that a contradiction is reached **for any** particular neighborhood $N\subseteq S$.

Hence, **for any** neighborhood $N$ you do have $N\cap(\mathbb R\setminus S)\not=\emptyset$. This is what is used later on.