# If $x$ is an isolated point of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ is a boundary point of $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Is the following proof valid? (Note: I know there is a post discussing this problem, but I am curious to see if my argument works). This problem is different from [another post that is similar with this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646909/is-there-a-problem-with-this-professors-proof-concerning-interior-and-boundary), because my proof begins with an existential neighborhood and ultimately considers a different route in proving the problem.

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $x$ is an isolated point of $S$, then $x$ is a boundary point of $S$.

Suppose that $x$ is an isolated point of $S$ and assume to the contrary that $x$ is not a boundary point of $S$. Then for each $x$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $N_{\epsilon} \subseteq S$. But because $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$, we see that for each $x$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $N_{\delta}^* \cap S = \varnothing$ where $N_{\delta}^*$ is some deleted neighborhood. Therefore, $N_{\delta}^* \subseteq S^c$.

Thus there are two intervals centered at $x$, and either $\epsilon \geq \delta$ or $\delta \geq \epsilon$, which would then imply that $N_{\delta}^* \subseteq N_{\epsilon}$ for the former and $N_{\epsilon} \subseteq N_{\delta}^*$ for the latter (it helps to draw a picture of these intervals to see why these cases arise). But in both cases we reach a contradiction, because these possibilities imply that $N \not \subseteq S$. Therefore, there are no $N_{\epsilon}$'s contained in $S$, but because $x \in S$, we deduce that every neighborhood $N$ must satisfy $N \cap S \neq \varnothing$ and $N \cap S^c \neq \varnothing$. Hence, $x$ is a boundary point of $S$.

Comment: Looks good to me, though a bit dense (spacing would help).

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, sir.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense  to say "for each $x$" in this circumstance, even though it is accurate.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire  Wait for other proofreaders — I'm only awake because of caffeine right now.

Comment: @CameronBuie I suggested drawing a picture in case my claim that either one of the neighborhoods is a subset of the other. So, is there a problem with the logic of my proof?

Comment: There is, unfortunately, but not an irreparable problem. See my answer.

Comment: The only piece of information in your post that is relevant to how I attempted to solve the problem is the rejection that $N_{\epsilon}$ cannot be contained in $N_{\delta}^*$, which makes sense, but then we have to consider the possibility that $N_{\delta}^*  \subseteq N_{\epsilon}$, which is also false. Therefore, $N$ cannot be contained in $S$, right?

Comment: It is entirely possible that $N_\delta^*\not\subseteq N_\epsilon$ and $N_\epsilon\not\subseteq N_\delta^*.$ In particular, this happens precisely if $\delta>\epsilon,$ so considering only the $N_\delta^*\subseteq N_\epsilon$ case is not exhaustive, *a priori*. You can *prove* that we may assume $\delta\le\epsilon$ without loss of generality, which is basically the approach I suggested in my answer. Also, it isn't immediately clear (to me) why $N_\delta^*\subseteq N_\epsilon$ should imply that "$N\not\subseteq S$" (whatever you mean by "$N$"), so that's probably worth expanding upon.

Comment: That $N$ should be $N_{\epsilon}$

Comment: In that case, I *do* see why it follows that $N\not\subseteq S$. Still, it takes but a few words to explain, so you should do so. It is acceptable practice for textbooks to leave such details to the reader, but not a good personal practice.

Comment: So is there a problem with my proof? If so, please show me how the proof doesn't work, because, if we have two intervals $N_{\epsilon}$ and $N_{\delta}^*$ centered at $x$, then there must be three possibilities: Either $\epsilon < \delta$, $\delta < \epsilon$ or $\delta = \epsilon$. But in all three cases, there is a contradiction, so we conclude that $N_{\epsilon}$ cannot exist. But because $x \in S$, it follows that every neighborhood $N$ must have a nonempty intersection with $S$ and the complement $S^c$. What is the problem?

Comment: $N_\delta^*$ is not an interval. That's really the only thing wrong with the proof, and it's easily fixed.

Comment: I could just not call $N_{\delta}^*$ N interval, since you are technically right, but it's true what I have said about the two neighborhoods nonetheless, right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x\in N_\epsilon$ and $x\notin N_\delta^*,$ so we can't have $N_\epsilon\subseteq N_\delta^*.$ Rather, we can conclude that $N_\delta\subseteq N_\epsilon$ or $N_\epsilon\subseteq N_\delta.$

I would recommend proving your claims about $N_\epsilon$ and $N_\delta$ explicitly, rather than asking your reader to draw a picture. For one thing, one can be misled by pictures, and for another, it helps you to make certain you're on the right track with your proof. It helps to consider $$N:=N_\epsilon\cap N_\delta=N_{\min(\epsilon,\delta)},$$ and use the assumptions to show that $N\subseteq S$ and $N^*\cap S=\emptyset,$ so that $N=\{x\},$ which is absurd.

Alternately, the simplest proof is not by contradiction, but direct!

> Suppose $x$ is an isolated point of $S,$ so that there is some $\delta>0$ such that $N_\delta(x)\cap S=\{x\}.$ Take any neighborhood $U$ of $x.$ By definition, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $N_\epsilon(x)\subseteq U.$ Put $c=\min\{\delta,\epsilon\},$ so $c>0.$ Put $y=x+\frac12c.$ Then $y\ne x$ and $|y-x|<\delta,$ so $y\notin S.$ But $|y-x|<\epsilon,$ so $y\in U.$ Thus, $S^c\cap U\ne\emptyset,$ and trivially $S\cap U\ne\emptyset,$ and so $x$ is a boundary point of $S.$

Comment: @downvoter: If you see an issue with this answer, please point it out, so I can improve it.

Comment: In reference to your first paragraph, if $N_{\epsilon}$ and $N_{\delta}^*$ have the same center, then either one of the two overlaps the other or the lengths are equal. If all of these possibilities lead to contradictions, then no such $\epsilon$ exists, so there are no $N_{\epsilon} \subseteq S$, which is what I was trying to prove.

Comment: You're absolutely right: if all of those possibilities lead to contradictions (which they do), then no such $\epsilon$ exists. There are two issues with this: (1) proceeding by cases makes for a longer proof, and (2) you've not demonstrated the contradictions yet.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't sure if I should give detailed explanations how these cases all lead to contradictions, because they are so straightforward as to be omitted and left for the reader as to not deter from the main point of the proof, as some textbooks do. Should I still give reasons for each case, even though they are straightforward to derive? And when I say straightforward, I mean that the reader has to simply use definitions.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the purpose. If the proof is for self-edification or a text meant for other students to read, there's no harm in leaving small gaps for the reader to fill in. If it's for homework, you should probably be explicit.

Comment: Gotcha. I also liked your direct approach, which I prefer a direct approach, but doing so for me was difficult.